# Javascript smooth scroll without jumping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a script where I once I reach a specific point of the screen the div starts to scroll with the body by adding a fixed position, but it is not smooth and looks horrible. I have not been able to understand if I can add a pageoffset instead of adding a fixed class which causes the div to slightly jump instead of just picking up from where it is.

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var scrolledElement = document.getElementById('ID');
    var top = scrolledElement.offsetTop;
    var listener = function ()
    {
        var y = scrolledElement.scrollTop || scrolledElement.scrollTop || window.pageYOffset;

        if (y >= top)
        {
            scrolledElement.classList.add('fixed');
        } else {
            scrolledElement.classList.remove('fixed');
        }
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', listener, false);
}
```

but as I said, whenever the body scroll reaches the ID div it just jumps and adds the fixed css which is..

```
#ID.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 336px; 
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

I can't understand if by adding offsettop to it instead of css it would make it not jump?

Comment: Hi @iBrazilian2, when you take the element to a fixed position, the jump is likely the other elements in the page changing to their new relative position. Try adding container `div` to the element you want to fix with a given height. So when it changes position, the other elements on the page stay relatively where they are.

Comment: Sadly that didn't workout too well.

Comment: hard to track down things like this without seeing your hmtml/css - are you able to recreate a simplified demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: @RobSedgwick I can show you the exact page, at the right side there is a section and it says "content goes here" http://goo.gl/UWJc0i

Comment: Works/'feels' ok when we take the margin-top off the 'fixed' class - so how about adding that margin into the `top` calculation ? - eg `if (y >= top+25)` ? - or listening for the `top` position of `#advertisement_right` so that it also takes into account the margin ?

Comment: I included (y >= top-25) instead of a + and it worked perfectly, thank you for your help.